# How do you write a file in a specific location on iPhone?

Tags: c++, iphone, file, mobile

I have been trying to create and write a file using an iPhone C++ compiler, but the file always ends up at a location called /tmp, which I do not have access to. Is there any way to use the iPhone to create and write a file to a specific path location?

I have tried to use the following code, but it does not create the file at that location:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    
    std::ofstream File("/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8EDE34D7-84CE-4147-8126-8D1AF04717A1/Documents/my_folder/my_file.txt");
    File << "Hello!";
    File.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code ignores state of your `File` object. It just blindly attempts to write into it so no one knows what went wrong when opening it. There are lot of things that can go wrong but you should add code to check its state on any platform.

Two most common things that can go wrong:

Is `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8EDE34D7-84CE-4147-8126-8D1AF04717A1` certainly home directory of your app? You can not access files of another app, if you are trying to do that. Normally you should request your app home directory from operating system, with [CFCopyHomeDirectoryURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1620446-cfcopyhomedirectoryurl?preferredLanguage=occ) or perhaps `getenv` works too:

```
std::string home = getenv("HOME");
```

If it is directory of your app then you still can not create files in directory `my_folder` if that directory inside `Documents` directory of your app does not exist. For that you need to use  [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager) or perhaps `mkdir` from `sys/stat.h` works too.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to use getenv: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted

Comment: Why you did not try CFCopyHomeDirectoryURL? Seems that getenv returns NULL but I can't replicate that behavior. Are you certain that you used literally getenv("HOME")? Where you try to run it? Is it for sure running on iPhone (or simulator of one), and not on Mac itself or Android phone (or simulator)?

Comment: I use the code with "HOME". I am still trying to figure out how to use CFCopyHomeDirectoryURL. The compiler is C/C++ compiler by Learn and code in C/C++, and it is an online compiler.

Comment: Online compilers do not run the code on your devices, perhaps you are confused what you are doing.  I have heard of no other ways to make applications for iPhone than to buy a Mac and to use XCode.